# Mês com dois dígitos no getMonth, mas está dando erro

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando colocar dois dígitos no `getMonth`, mas está dando erro. O que estou fazendo de errado?

```js
var data = new Date();
var dia = ("0" + data.getDate()).slice(-2);
var mes = ("0" + (data.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var ano4 = data.getFullYear();
var hora = ("0" + data.getHours()).slice(-2);
var min = ("0" + data.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
var str_data = dia + '/' + (mes + 1) + '/' + ano4;
var str_hora = hora + ':' + min;

console.log(str_data + " " + str_hora);
```

Comment: Não entendi esse `(mes + 1)`... está concatenando o mês + o número 1. Talvez devesse ser apenas `mes`, assim: `var str_data = dia + '/' + mes + '/' + ano4;`

Comment: @Sam Erra isso mesmo...rsrs Obrigado.

Comment: Talvez seu codigo possa ficar mais efetivo usando o https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está concatenando a string da variável `mes` com o número 1 neste trecho:

```
var str_data = dia + '/' + (mes + 1) + '/' + ano4;
```

Veja que nesta linha a variável `mes` é uma string:

```
var mes = ("0" + (data.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
```

O correto seria usar apenas `mes` e não `mes + 1`:

```
var str_data = dia + '/' + mes + '/' + ano4;
```

**Código:**

```js
var data = new Date();
var dia = ("0" + data.getDate()).slice(-2);
var mes = ("0" + (data.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var ano4 = data.getFullYear();
var hora = ("0" + data.getHours()).slice(-2);
var min = ("0" + data.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
var str_data = dia + '/' + mes + '/' + ano4;
var str_hora = hora + ':' + min;

console.log(str_data + " " + str_hora);
```